# keyboard module thread cant be closed at application exit

Tags: python, keyboard, exit, hotkeys

- I am creating a hotkey as follows:

**import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey ('win+esc', close_application)**

- The close_application function is what the hotkey calls is:

**def close_application ():**

**keyboard.unhook_all_hotkeys()**

**sys.exit()**

- Problem:

Application never exist, as a sub thread creating automatically by keybard.hotkey function, never closes:

[image]

I tried all different ways to exit from the application as well as some other methods of keyboard module to release the hotkey, but none was successful.

May I ask if you have any idea how can i force to close the thread opened by the keyboard module ?

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details including information on your platform. Anyway if you don't care to skip cleanup routines, what about calling ```os._exit()```?

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed os._exit (os.EX_OK) worked perfectly. Many thanks!